# autostart node.js script at a given time

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, scrape, cheerio

I am using a node.js/express.js script to scrap data from a website. The data I need are generated on a daily basis, so I need my script to launch automatically everyday at a given hour.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What type of server is your script running on (V-/Root-Server, some NodeJs hosting, your local machine,  something else?)? If you're on a Unix/Linux environment you might look for "Cronjobs"

Comment: I am using Wamp Server on Windows to run my script on my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a node problem, you just need to launch the script (like any other) on a regular basis. On linux/mac, it's via cronjobs, on windows it's via schtasks

All available commands can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx

Or you can use the windows "click around" way:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 1):

if you are on linux and you want do it using only node js, you can use [node-schedule](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule).

```
 schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 14, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 0}, function(){
    console.log('Time for tea!');
});
```